# Child process - listen for event when parent dies

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, process, subshell

I have a detached child process. It knows its parent's pid. Is there some way on both MacOS and Linux that I can listen for when the parent process exits, from the child process?

I need to make a call to delete a lockfile from the child, when the parent process dies.

*I am looking for a solution that does not require polling.*

I heard that `waitid()` might do it. I have this small program that compiles on MacOS with gcc, but it exits with code 255 - my only guess is that this is because waitid() won't work with processes that aren't child process of the current process?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    pid_t pid = atoi(argv[1]);
    printf("pid = %jd\n", (intmax_t) pid);
    siginfo_t sig;
    return waitid(P_PID, pid, &sig, WEXITED|WNOWAIT);
}
```

Comment: Why not `ps` for PPID?

Comment: because that would require polling, right?

Comment: And what's the problem with that? Put it in your question.

Comment: Yeah I am looking for a solution that does not require polling, I will put that in the question - if 100s of programs on your machine use polling, it just causes performance degradation - it's like polluting right

Comment: You could create a pipe before forking, close the reading end in the parent, the writing end in the child and have the child use `select()`/`poll()`/`read()` to detect the pipe going away when the parent dies (which would cause the writing end of the pipe to be closed, and `read()` to return for instance)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I am trying to create a very convenient (one-line) reusable library that can lock a script so that it can only run once, etc, this is what I have so far: https://github.com/ORESoftware/quicklock, it works, but the MacOS solution uses polling.

Comment: Here is what I use to determine if the parent process has died: https://github.com/ORESoftware/quicklock/blob/master/unlock.ts#L50

Comment: the problem is that on MacOS/Darwin, lsof is polling every second (that's what `r+ 1` is doing)

Comment: Compare ˋgetppidˋ with the original pid. This implies polling, but if your child processes should do something else than waiting for their parent to die, polling for ppid is probably quite near to an optimal solution.

Comment: Yeah I am looking for something evented, I have a deep hatred for polling if it can be avoided

Comment: this is on point I think: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2050/_index.html

Comment: dtruss, dtrace, strace, ptrace, are probably closer to what I want, but some of those require root privileges

Answer (score 0):

On MacOS, the following actually has the behavior I am looking for (and possibly doesn't use polling?)

https://github.com/brainopener/mac-pid-waiter

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/event.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    pid_t pid;    
    if(argc!=2 || (pid=atoi(argv[1]))<=0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"USAGE\nwaiter pid\n");
        return 1;
    }

    int kq=kqueue();
    if (kq == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr,"kqueue returned -1.");
    return 1;
    }

    struct kevent ke;    
    EV_SET(&ke, pid, EVFILT_PROC, EV_ADD, NOTE_EXIT, 0, NULL);

    if (kevent(kq, &ke, 1, NULL, 0, NULL)<0) {
        fprintf(stderr,"kevent failed.");
    return 1;
    }


    for(;;) {
        memset(&ke,0,sizeof(struct kevent));
        if(kevent(kq, NULL, 0, &ke, 1, NULL)<0){
            fprintf(stderr,"kevent failed.");
        return 1;
        }

        if (ke.fflags & NOTE_EXIT)
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```